# breakpoints in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

I think this may have been asked earlier but i can't find one that satisfied my requirements.

I am debugging(infact trying to understand) a large project by trying to analyze the code flow in various testsuites. But when i try to set breakpoints at some files, i get the error "no source file named filename found".
So my question is:

1. Can gdb only accept breakpoints for the source files where the code flow enters.?
2. Can I  set breakpoints over entire lines of a file with something like `b filename:*`
3. Will a breakpoint at header file be accepted as header files are just appended at compile time?

Any insights are more than welcome.

**Edit**
I checked these issues with some hello world code and found same results as pointed out in one of the answers.but my issue in the actual project still remains on. I still get the same error even when i can see the edited output of the same line which is not accepted as a breakpoint.

**Edit 2**
I got it working but don't understand how and why it works..??

```
(gdb) b /home/neeraj/BTP/trunk/include/header.h:872
No source file named /home/neeraj/BTP/trunk/include/header.h:872
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) b /home/neeraj/BTP/trunk/src/driver.cpp:2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x806c61a: file ../../../trunk/src/driver.cpp, line 2.
(gdb) b /home/neeraj/BTP/trunk/include/header.h:872
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8052fa0: file ../../../trunk/include/header.h:872, line 872.
(gdb)
```

Any deeper insights..?

Comment: Beware shared libraries.  You might want to try setting your breakpoints after any shared libraries are loaded.  For the most common case: put a breakpoint on main, run the program, then (once in main) set your breakpoints.

Comment: @Managu thanks your comment inspired my successful trial and error effort.. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other thing to beware of besides shared libraries is that `gdb` source file names are relative to the directory where the code was compiled.  If you haven't compiled with absolute pathnames, use the `dir` command to add the compilation directory to the list of places `gdb` searches for source code.

And a hint: I find I am wildly more productive when I use the [Data Display Debugger (DDD)](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) graphical front end to `gdb`.

Comment: thanks.. that worked like a charm.. infact the entire behavior was due to the include path not being in the path to be searched.

Answer (score 8):

1. No.
2. No.
3. Yes.

Make sure you compile with -g (debug) option. Make sure the sourcepaths are set correctly. Use  directory, show directories and dir commands to see/set.