# How to use gdb on c++ header files?

Tags: c++, debugging, header, gdb

I tried to search this question online, but it seems that I can't find a good solution for my problem. Well, I'm trying to use gdb to debug my c++ program. And the program is made up of a simple main.cpp and a model.h. And the compiling command is

```
g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp
g++ -Wall -g main.o -o OUTPUT
```

As almost all the algorithm is stored in model.h, I need to debug that header file rather than the cpp file. However, whenever I tried to place a break point on the header like

```
tbreak model.h:163
```

gdb always give me a message that"No source file named TNFmodel.h".

In another question [breakpoints in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810415/breakpoints-in-gdb), I saw a solution by adding the folder that containing the header into the library by "dir". But my header file is already in source folder, and after trying

```
dir ./
```

The problem maintains.

So anybody know what's wrong? How to use gdb to debug a header file?

Comment: was the header also included from that location when compiling? Maybe you can post the output gdb gives when entering `info sources`.

Comment: Ouch... I checked the sources, and saw the problem now... The case of a letter wasn't match. Well, I don't know how I passed compiling... But maybe it's because I'm using mac, and sometimes cases are not sensitive when compiling. After correcting the case, the gdb works fine for the header. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/760746/nobody, one way to make sure the header to be in the sources is to veryfy it by checking

```
info sources
```

After ensuring the header itself be in the sources(in my case, the problem is that the case of a letter in the header name was mixed up, and somehow it went through the compiling on my mac book), inserting breakpoint in lines of a header file works just fine.

Comment: The reason it works on mac book is that the disk was formatted into case-insensitive, thus the case of the filename didn't make any differences.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use break with your class/method name like this:

```
break  class::method
```

Comment: So I can't go directly inside a line of that method, but have to go to the method first and then track to the line I want it to break? That sounds... not so convenient...

Comment: I don't know any other possibility, sry dude

Comment: Me neither, that's why I'm asking... Sometimes lacking this function is really inconvenient...

Answer (score 1):

What I've found is that is that the file names are sometimes shortened. Using `info sources` I was able to find the shortened name that GCC used. When I set the breakpoint using the shortened file name, GDB correctly set the breakpoint.

For example the file `CommonLibrary\headers\Endian.h` was changed to `COM~2\headers\Endian.h`

This on Windows 10, running mingw-64.