# No source file named main.c. gdb break point setting

Tags: c, gdb, cygwin, breakpoints

I am using gdb for debugging C project source code. I compile as shown:

```
./configure --enable-debug CFLAGS="-g -o0" 
make --debug=a
```

I want to debugging stop at specific file. So when I set break point by using

```
(gdb) break main.c:672
```

It says:

```
No source file named main.c.
```

Even when I pass specific function name (in main.c file) to break  . it says: such function not defined.

My current directory has this main.c file. I am using Cygwin on Windows. When I set break point by using

```
(gdb) break main
```

It set break point at a main function of Cygwin file, not in my source code.

1. how can I fix my first problem?
2. just curious, how to avoid second problem, if there is same function name within Cygwin files and my source code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're compiling with `-g` and still not able to set a breakpoint, try adding `raise(SIGTRAP)` in your `main()`, run the process in gdb, then set the breakpoint you want again after it hits the `SIGTRAP`.

Answer (score 13):

When you compile your `.c` file, make sure you use:

```
gcc filename.c -g 

gdb <binary name>
```

Search for load debugging symbols done or not?

If not:

```
gdb) symbol-file <path-of-symbol-file>
```

you can find symbol file in obj directory

Comment: Reading symbols from .libs/slim...done.   it showed that message, I think loading symbols is ok.

Comment: you can post the snapshot of the whole problem means how you are compiling

Comment: I added compile info , please review

Comment: just check  you have to add symbol file of the process id

Comment: I did not see any such file. what is extended name of that file? I don't have obj directory.

Comment: The message is displayed when load executable: Reading symbols from .libs/slim...done

Comment: hope this links guide you for that [gdb using cygwin]http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/gdb.html

Answer (score 4):

Crucial is gcc parameter -g during compilation.

Everything else is secondary.

See [breakpoints in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810447/1329132)

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered with similar problem earlier. I just deleted **.metadata** folder and imported the particular project again and that work well.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have to use GDB, type the following in command line

```
gcc -g -o outputfile sourcefile.c
```

Now type

```
gdb -tui outputfile
```

and then enter the break command

Comment: gdb -tui outputfile .   I run this and it opened an area on the top of terminal, it has message "no source available". after that I tried to set break, and same "No source file named main.c." message.